# Dictionary<T1, T2> How can I use this in short name?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I'm using a dictionary called `Dictionary<MyProperty, string>` to use in all my source codes.

And I want to change the name into something shorter, which has the same effect, 
because the `Dictionary<MyProperty, string>` is a bit too long.

I mean:
change

```
Dictionary<MyProperty, string> mydic = new Dictionary<MyProperty, string>();
```

into

```
MyDic mydic = new MyDic();
```

And I want to use it the same as Dictionary, like

```
mydic[myProperty] = "somestring";
```

How do I achieve this?

I tried

```
public class MyDic : Dictionary<MyProperty, string>
{
}
```

but it doesn't work, or should I add something?

Comment: Actually, yes, and I want to use this pattern in all my projects, and it won't be changed. How to do that?

Comment: "It doesn't work"?? What doesn't work?

Comment: Also... Surely the intellisense of VS saves you typing much more than the first D?

Comment: MyProperty is a strange name for a class or a struct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me
I just tested
What do you mean it does not work?

```
TestCast tc3 = new TestCast(5757);
MyDic myDic = new MyDic();
myDic.Add(tc3, "string");
myDic[tc3] = "string2";


public class MyDic : Dictionary<MyProperty, string>
{
}
```

Personally unless you are going override then just use

```
Dictionary<MyProperty, string> mydic = new Dictionary<MyProperty, string>();
```

So a few keystrokes.  It is just one line and pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Works for me too! I also prefer this to aliasing! Much more obvious!

Comment: using inheritance just to have an alias of a class? IMHO it is not a good idea. @BenjaminPaul

Comment: Why not out of interest? @dotctor

Comment: Using inheritance to do aliasing has the problem of requiring you redefine the relevant constructors. Since it will quickly become unreasonable to do that everywhere, it's probably best to avoid it for consistency's sake.

Comment: Ok, it works, I don't know why it has error at the first try. Maybe it's because the VS has some strange errors. I restarted it, and it worked.

Comment: Usually you'll be using this approach when you want something more semantic than Dictionary<> . It's also more maintainable if you need to add properties/behaviour later.

Comment: Come on down vote.  What it the problem with answering the question?

Answer (score 3):

you can use type aliases in C#. also consider using `var` instead of full name if it is possible

```
using MyDic = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<MyProperty, string>;
```

later instantiate a variable like

```
MyDic mydic = new MyDic(); // or var mydic = new MyDic()
```

you can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

---

you can also use inheritance to just rename a type like what you did before

```
public class MyDic : Dictionary<MyProperty, string> { }
```

Using inheritance to do aliasing has the problem of requiring you redefine the relevant constructors. Since it will quickly become unreasonable to do that everywhere, it's probably best to avoid it for consistency's sake.

---

Finally. Please don't do it. When people see this code

```
var MyDic = new Dictionary<MyProperty, string>;
```

they understand immediately that it is a dictionary of `string`s with `MyProperty` as key.

but when they see:

```
var MyDic = new MyDic();
```

they must go and find out what `MyDic` is! One programmer's saving on typing could very well be the next programmer's maintenance nightmare, writing readable code is a good idea.

Comment: This is just an opinion but IMO this would be really confusing to another developer who has to read this code.

Comment: I disagree, A base class would be much more preferable.